# Moving configuration outside of IIS root

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration-files, asp.net-core-2.0

In regular ASP.NET/MVC development we could move configuration entries from `web.config` in the application/site directory to `machine.config`.

With ASP.NET Core is there something similar, now that we have json based configuration files?

Comment: Yes, you can set the absolute path in your Startup.cs, when adding the appsettings.json.

Comment: You can specify different json config files to use when configuring your host in Program.cs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, technically, you can pull in any JSON from any location. Just pass the full filesystem path, instead of just "appsettings.json".

However, really, if you're talking about externalizing your configuration, you should probably use environment variables or some service like Azure Key Vault.